# VBA: Loop multiplication until specific value

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I am trying to create a loop in Word VBA which is multiplying any given number from an textbox input but the answer should never exceed the number 100.

This is what I am having right now:

```
Dim varcounter As Integer
Dim varnumber As Integer
Dim varcx As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 varnumber = Val(TextBox1)
 varcounter = 1
 While solution < 100
  varcx = varcounter
  varcx = varcx & " x "
  varcx = varcx & varnumber
  varcx = varcx & " = "
  solution = varcounter * varnumber
  varcx = varcx & solution 

  ListBox1.AddItem (varcx)

  varcounter = varcounter + 1
 Wend

End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that it will always exceed or equal 100 because the previous multiplication does not meet the condition. How can I change this code so that it would not exceed 100? Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like `while varcounter * varnumber>100`

Comment: btw, the multiplication symbol (e.g. `×` not `x`) is `Chr(215)`.

Comment: And @Nathan_Sav  you mean "<" instead of ">"

Comment: yes, sorry <100 :)  long day today

Answer (score 1):

Preload a `For ... Next` loop with a calculated termination.

```
Option Explicit

Dim varcounter As Integer
Dim varnumber As Integer
Dim varcx As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    varnumber = Val(TextBox1)
    For varcounter = 1 To Int(99.999 / varnumber)
        varcx = varcounter & Chr(32) & Chr(215) & Chr(32) & varcounter * varnumber
        Debug.Print varcx
        ListBox1.AddItem varcx
    Next varcounter

End Sub
```

I've used 99.999 instead of 100 since you wanted '*less than*' and not '*less than or equal to*'. Use `Int(...)` and not `CInt(...)`; `CInt(...)` will round off while `Int(...)` rounds down by stripping off any decimal portion.

Answer (score 0):

you just check the *foreseen* value:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    varnumber = Val(TextBox1)
    While solution + varnumber < 100
        varcounter = varcounter + 1
        solution = varcounter * varnumber
        varcx = varcounter & " x " & varnumber & " = " & solution
        ListBox1.AddItem (varcx)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the OP has moved on, but wanted to add a possible answer for posterity's sake...

```
varnumber = Val(TextBox1.Value)
varcounter = 1
solution =  varcounter * varnumber
While solution < 100
    varcx = varcounter & " x " & varnumber & " = " & solution
    Listbox1.AddItem varcx
    varcounter = varcounter + 1
    solution = varcounter * varnumber
Wend
```